# left of '.expression' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

In this code I have an object that contains two variables hours and minutes. Im trying to consecutively add a value of 15 minutes and a value of 20 minutes to an object called t1. But I get the error : left of '.plus' must have class/struct/union.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>        
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

class Time {
public:
Time(int u, int m);
Time(int g);
void plus(Time t);
void plus(int x);
void print();

private:
int min;
int hour;
};

void Time::plus(Time t) {
min += t.min;
 if (min > 59) {
    hour++;
    min = min - 60;
 }
}

void Time::plus(int x) {
min += x;
 if (min > 59) {
    hour++;
    min = min - 60;
 }
}

void Time::print() {

cout << setw(2) << hour << " hour and " << min << " minutes";
}

Time::Time(int u, int m) : hour(u), min(m) {

}

Time::Time(int m) : hour(0), min(m) {
}


int main() {
Time t1(1, 10);        
const Time kw(15);     
t1.plus(kw).plus(20);     
cout << "t1 = "; t1.print(); cout << endl;
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your `plus` returns `void`, or nothing! So you can't do `t1.plus(kw).plus(20);`. If you want to, you need to have your `.plus()` return a `Time`:

```
class Time {
public:
    Time &plus(Time t);
    Time &plus(int x);
    ...
};
```

I've gone ahead and made it return a `Time` by reference so that when you chain the function like you are, the next `plus` will still modify the original object the first `plus` was called on! We can do this if you implement the `plus` functions like:

```
Time &Time::plus(Time t) {
min += t.min;
 if (min > 59) {
    hour++;
    min = min - 60;
 }
 return *this; //return ourselves so that the next func will be called on us too!
}

Time &Time::plus(int x) {
min += x;
 if (min > 59) {
    hour++;
    min = min - 60;
 }
 return *this; //return ourselves so that the next func will be called on us too!
}
```

Comment: Also: it's more usual to name this function `operator+=` rather than `plus`